# Own filter Solr

Tags: solr, filter, addition, token

have long since I have been researching, but so far have not found anything to solve my problem. I'm trying to create a filter for Solr, which add a TOKEN. For example, the entry is "Football" and the output is "Football" and "Brazil." If possible I would like a practical example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is. Do you want to add Tokens for certain words? e.g. if a user searches for _Audi_ the system should also search for _Car_ ...?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a filter you can use [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) to add Synonyms as mentioned in your example.
This will allow you map terms and related terms, which would get added to the index.

Comment: Yes, @Jayendra is correct. This is where my question was heading to. If you want to add tokens for certain words Synonyms are the way to go.